# Best message for "more posts" at the end of page (no pagination involved)

Tags: ux-designer, pagination, messages

In my free time I'm building my site/blog from scratch using Jekyll (a template engine). Despite Jekyll has first-class support for pagination I want to avoid it so **only the latest *X* posts are visible in my home page**. If a user want to see older posts **they should use the archive or make a search**.

My question is: **how can I invite users to do this?**

This is my *work in progress* attempt:

[image: no pagination]

Any suggestion? Is there a better way? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your current solution is good for the described use case.** My only (subjective) gripe with it is that you are giving options when I prefer when designers are taking care of the general experience and are navigating the user instead.

I would probably ditch the search (which should be easily accessible anyway and most likely, from some other, more obvious place), and make the link to archive the primary action of this block.

*Also, I don't think you need to explain why you are doing it this way.*

Answer (score 1):

You should just name your post list "Latest posts", and add two buttons close enough; 
 
- See all posts(37) 
 
- Search 

IMO, rest is redudant.